# Post Large Images/ Pictures on facebook timeline via Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-timeline

I want to post a photo status on my page timeline but unable to post it. I am able to post status,link,link with thumbnail etc.. I only want to post a photo status via Graph API. I'm using PHP.

Answer (score 3):

try this
**if you have picture url**

```
$picUrl = 'http://somedomain.com/picture.jpg';
$photoId = $facebook->api("me/photos","POST",array('url'=>$picUrl,'message'=>"status message"));
```

**OR if you have image file on your machine**

```
$imgPath = '@' . realpath($imgfile);
$photoId = $facebook->api("me/photos","POST",array('image'=>$imgPath,'message'=>"status message"));
```

Comment: This is adding photo in the album but its not posting over the timeLine